# Coveralls in travis-ci outputs no report file available and repo token as null

Tags: github, travis-ci, coveralls

I am trying to integrate Travis ci and coveralls with jacoco plugin into my public android GitHub repository. I can successfully run Travis with my repository now. To add coveralls, I have used [coveralls gradle plugin](https://github.com/kt3k/coveralls-gradle-plugin) as I built project with gradle. I managed to get Travis to successfully build with coveralls however in Travis ci, coveralls task is skipped and in output it says repo token : null and no report file available. I currently have no tests in project, can this be the reason? In that case shouldn't it just say 0% ? If I need tests to activate coveralls report how can I write tests that coveralls can read? Also I activated repository through coveralls website.

[My build.gradle](https://github.com/lemikistu/Android-Alternative-Animations/blob/master/build.gradle)

[My travis.yml](https://github.com/lemikistu/Android-Alternative-Animations/blob/master/.travis.yml)

[My travis ci output](https://travis-ci.com/lemikistu/Android-Alternative-Animations/builds/111928648)

Thanks.